# how to Show Add-To-Cart quantity box on FEATURED PRODUCT in virtuemart with ajax use

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

How to Show Add-To-Cart quantity box on FEATURED PRODUCT with ajax use

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize this section.

If any where you want to add addtocart button and qty box you can just copy the default VM cart form from details page.
this form have some hidden fields like

```
 virtuemart_product_id,virtuemart_catgory_id ,qty
```

The name of this fileds make same and the form submitting to the addjs function in the cart.php controller.
inside this form you just create  qty box.

Best of luck